# error sending mail in python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

```
pwd = "mypassword"
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login("gvpcse113@gmail.com",pwd)

msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"
server.sendmail("gvpcse113@gmail.com", "sender@xyz.com", msg)
server.quit()
```

I have tried sending a mail through python...
Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/my projects/PythonCourse/test_cont/mail_test4.py", line 4, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I am connecting through a proxy connection
I set the proxy through cmd in windows.
Please help me with this.

**Update :** 

I am sure with the internet connection :

```
import urllib2

def internet_on():
    try:
        response=urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.co.in',timeout=1)
        return True
    except urllib2.URLError as err: pass
    return False

print internet_on()
```

Output is `True`

Comment: is it working without proxy ? Maybe problem is your proxy, not Python code.

Comment: Look like you don't have proper DNS resolution, wich is not uncommon for proxied networks. Unluckily we can not give advise since a) we don't know anything about your network and b) network configuration issues are out of the scope of SO.

Comment: Please have a look at the update

Comment: smtp.gmail.com must be accessed on port 465 (SSL required) or
port 587 (TLS required) [docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

Answer (score 7):

Your code works fine for me, so it's probably the connection settings.

Try changing server to:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('64.233.184.108')
```

(that's the IP address of smtp.gmail.com, to bypass DNS resolution)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
```

to include a port. The port for gmail is 587, so add that as a second parameter:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

If this does not work, make sure that you have used this site to make sure that the account will let you in:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps